# How to migrate `SignalR`references from `ASP .NET` to `ASP .NET Core` with `Razor` pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-signalr

There is an example from MS website (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-server-broadcast-with-signalr) to create a web application that uses `ASP.NET` `SignalR` to provide server broadcast of some stock prices.

I am trying to figure out what sort of adjustments do I need to carry out to make it work under `ASP.NET Core`. With `ASP.NET Core`, some fo the statements do not work (marked with between (***) comments).

The underlying object in "Stock.cs" is characterised by:

```
Stock.Symbol
Stock.Price
Stock.Open
Stock.Change
Stock.ChangePercent
```

Under `ASP.NET`, we have a client in "StockTicker.cs" defined by:

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;

namespace SignalR.StockTicker
{
    public class StockTicker
    {
        // *** Name GlobalHost does not exist ***
        private readonly static Lazy<StockTicker> _instance = new Lazy<StockTicker>(() => new StockTicker(GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<StockTickerHub>().Clients));

        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Stock> _stocks = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Stock>();

        private readonly object _updateStockPricesLock = new object();

        private readonly double _rangePercent = .002;

        private readonly TimeSpan _updateInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250);
        private readonly Random _updateOrNotRandom = new Random();

        private readonly Timer _timer;
        private volatile bool _updatingStockPrices = false;

        // *** No IHubConnectionContext type or namespace name ***
        private StockTicker(IHubConnectionContext<dynamic> clients)
        {
            Clients = clients;

            _stocks.Clear();
            var stocks = new List<Stock>
            {
                new Stock { Symbol = "MSFT", Price = 30.31m },
                new Stock { Symbol = "APPL", Price = 578.18m },
                new Stock { Symbol = "GOOG", Price = 570.30m }
            };
            stocks.ForEach(stock => _stocks.TryAdd(stock.Symbol, stock));

            _timer = new Timer(UpdateStockPrices, null, _updateInterval, _updateInterval);

        }

        public static StockTicker Instance
        {
            get
            {
                return _instance.Value;
            }
        }

        // *** No IHubConnectionContext type of namespace name ***
        private IHubConnectionContext<dynamic> Clients
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Stock> GetAllStocks()
        {
            return _stocks.Values;
        }

        private void UpdateStockPrices(object state)
        {
            lock (_updateStockPricesLock)
            {
                if (!_updatingStockPrices)
                {
                    _updatingStockPrices = true;

                    foreach (var stock in _stocks.Values)
                    {
                        if (TryUpdateStockPrice(stock))
                        {
                            BroadcastStockPrice(stock);
                        }
                    }

                    _updatingStockPrices = false;
                }
            }
        }

        private bool TryUpdateStockPrice(Stock stock)
        {
            // Randomly choose whether to update this stock or not
            var r = _updateOrNotRandom.NextDouble();
            if (r > .1)
            {
                return false;
            }

            // Update the stock price by a random factor of the range percent
            var random = new Random((int)Math.Floor(stock.Price));
            var percentChange = random.NextDouble() * _rangePercent;
            var pos = random.NextDouble() > .51;
            var change = Math.Round(stock.Price * (decimal)percentChange, 2);
            change = pos ? change : -change;

            stock.Price += change;
            return true;
        }

        private void BroadcastStockPrice(Stock stock)
        {
            // *** Invalid All method in the current context ***
            Clients.All.updateStockPrice(stock);
        }

    }
}
```

To register the `SignalR` route, I presume that I can do it directly in the "Program.cs" file. Instead of having the following "Startup.cs" file:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SignalR.StockTicker.Startup))]

namespace SignalR.StockTicker
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

I go for:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
// ==> Add SignalR here
builder.Services.AddSignalR();
```

and for:

```
app.MapRazorPages();
// ==> Map hub endpoint here
app.MapHub<StockTickerHub>("/StockTicker");

app.Run();
```

The cshtml page that returns the data is as follows:

```
@page
@model SignalR.Models.StockTickerModel
@{
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>ASP.NET SignalR Stock Ticker</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Segoe UI', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 16px;
        }
        #stockTable table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
            #stockTable table th, #stockTable table td {
                padding: 2px 6px;
            }
            #stockTable table td {
                text-align: right;
            }
            #stockTable .loading td {
            text-align: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>ASP.NET SignalR Stock Ticker Sample</h1>
    <h2>Live Stock Table</h2>
        <div id="stockTable">
        <table border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr><th>Symbol</th><th>Price</th><th>Open</th><th>Change</th><th>%</th></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="loading"><td colspan="5">loading...</td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <!--Script references. -->
    <!--Reference the jQuery library. -->
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" ></script>
    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <!--Reference the StockTicker script. -->
    <script src="StockTicker.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the simple underlying cshtml.cs page I have is:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages:

namespace SignalR.Pages
{
    public StockTickerModel : PageModel
    {
        public void OnGet()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I saw somewhere that the reference to `jQuery` is no longer required. The reference to the JS file "StockTicker.js" is:

```
if (!String.prototype.supplant) {
    String.prototype.supplant = function (o) {
        return this.replace(/{([^{}]*)}/g,
            function (a, b) {
                var r = o[b];
                return typeof r === 'string' || typeof r === 'number' ? r : a;
            }
        );
    };
}

$(function () {

    var ticker = $.connection.stockTickerHub, // the generated client-side hub proxy
        up = '▲',
        down = '▼',
        $stockTable = $('#stockTable'),
        $stockTableBody = $stockTable.find('tbody'),
        rowTemplate = '<tr data-symbol="{Symbol}"><td>{Symbol}</td><td>{Price}</td><td>{DayOpen}</td><td>{Direction} {Change}</td><td>{PercentChange}</td></tr>';

    function formatStock(stock) {
        return $.extend(stock, {
            Price: stock.Price.toFixed(2),
            PercentChange: (stock.PercentChange * 100).toFixed(2) + '%',
            Direction: stock.Change === 0 ? '' : stock.Change >= 0 ? up : down
        });
    }

    function init() {
        ticker.server.getAllStocks().done(function (stocks) {
            $stockTableBody.empty();
            $.each(stocks, function () {
                var stock = formatStock(this);
                $stockTableBody.append(rowTemplate.supplant(stock));
            });
        });
    }

    ticker.client.updateStockPrice = function (stock) {
        var displayStock = formatStock(stock),
            $row = $(rowTemplate.supplant(displayStock));

        $stockTableBody.find('tr[data-symbol=' + stock.Symbol + ']')
            .replaceWith($row);
        }

    $.connection.hub.start().done(init);

});
```

Comment: Here's a document  introduces the  differences between ASP.NET SignalR and ASP.NET Core SignalR:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/version-differences?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Comment: @RuikaiFeng Thanks you. I saw this. I find the directions pretty vague.